# Comparing two sets of tuples A and B to find size compatibility

Tags: python, recursion, merge, compatibility

Suppose we have n bed types, and surveyed n persons.
Let B = {b1, . . . , bn} be a set of n points in 2-dimensional space representing the dimensions of the bed
types. We write bi = (bi(x), bi(y)) with bi(x) representing the length of bed type i and bi(y) its width.
Similarly, we represent the requirements of the n persons with P = {p1, . . . , pn}, a set of n points in
2-dimensional space, and we also write pj = (pj (x), pj (y)) where pj (x) and pj (y) are person j’s length
and width requirements, respectively.
Point bi
is compatible with point pj if and only if bi(x) ≥ pj (x) and bi(y) ≥ pj (y). The compatibility
of bi
is the number of points of P that it is compatible with and we write comp(bi) = k if it is compatible
with k points of p.

We will start with the simpler 1-dimensional case, that is, P = {p1, . . . , pn} and B = {b1, . . . , bn} are
points in 1-dimensional space (multiple points may have the same value). Your task is to design an
O(n log n) time algorithm that computes the compatibility of each point in B with P.

I was thinking of using a binary search to locate the index of which the value of B is larger than the values of P(sorted) and that index location +1 should be the number of people compatible with the bed that i am looking for. I use a for loop to iterate through the sets of tuples representing beds and binary search each through the set P to find the index and print at each final step for output.

```
def binarySearch(arr,l,r,x):

    if r >= 1: #base case size must be greater or equal to 1

        mid = (r-1)//2 + 1
        if float(arr[mid][1] == float(x)) and float(arr[mid+1][1] == float(x)) and mid <= r-1:
            mid += 1    
        elif float(arr[mid][1]) <= float(x) and float(arr[mid+1][1]) > float(x):
            return mid
        if float(arr[mid][1]) >= float(x):
    #   if arr[mid][1] <= x:
            return binarySearch(arr,l,mid-1,x)
        else:
            return binarySearch(arr,mid+1,r,x)
    else:
        return -1


for i in range(len(b)): #p is set of sorted persons and b is set of beds

    x = b[i][1]

    numCompatible = binarySearch(p,0,len(p),x) + 1

    print(b[i][0],numCompatible)
```

I am receiving an error:

> "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison" with expected output being 
>   b1 10
>   b10 5
>   b11 11
>   b12 5
>   b13 5
>   b14 15
>   b15 13
>   b16 5
>   b2 3
>   b3 9
>   b4 10
>   b5 12
>   b6 9
>   b7 10
>   b8 4
>   b9 3

Comment: Python has a recursion limit. While the limit can be increased, it is a good pointer that your recursion goes so deep that you might want to come up with an iterative solution instead. Python is much better in interactions than recursions.